# How to change link color in NS2?

Tags: tcl, ns2

So here's my topology. In my tcl script i added a line to make the link between node 2 and 3 to go down at some point. As you can see (link below), NAM shows it in RED as soon as it goes down. What i want to do is to change that default color (red) to another color of my choice. Is it possible to that ? If yes, how?

http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/121995link.png

Answer (score 0):

you can assign your favorite color to the link by this instruction :

$ns duplex-link-op $n0 $n1 color green